# "Essere" or "stare" for the location of a building

Tags: word-usage, verbs, synonym

I know that "essere" is used for the current location of a moveable object (e.g. keys) and "stare" is used for the usual location of a moveable object, therefore I suppose that the latter is used with the position of a building (which does not move). However, I got confused because Google Translate has just translated "The building is in London" to "L'edificio è a Londra". Are both verbs correct here or is Google Translate wrong in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both options are correct as the location of buildings can be described with the verb “essere”.

- “Il palazzo sta a New York”/“Il palazzo è a New York”
- “La nostra baita è in cima alla montagna”/“La nostra baita sta in cima alla montagna”
- “La casa sta in via Trevano”/“La casa è in via Trevano”/“La casa si trova in via Trevano”

This really depends on which part of Italy you come from. I am from the north so I tend to prefer using the verb “essere”, but many people prefer “stare”.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that "stare" was obligatory because I have seen the meaning "to be located" with the example of a building in https://www.wordreference.com/iten/stare and there was no tag of regionalism on it.

Comment: Still on the subject "location of objects" in Standard Italian, "stare" is used for the usual location of objects, right? Ex: La chiave sta sul tavolo. I suppose I can express the same meaning with "essere di solito"? Ex: La chiave è di solito sul tavolo. Are both constructions equally usually in the north and in the south?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista “La chiave sta sul tavolo” may also just mean that the key is on the table, and I mostly would understand it so, out of context.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Unfortunately there are no general, “logical” rules for the use of _stare_ vs _essere_. Apart from particular cases (say, with the gerund), _essere_ rarely will fail you, while you'll learn the use of _stare_ paying attention to its idiomatic uses.

Comment: @DaG I have heard this rule about "stare" and the location of objects on this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEyosoHp8w0. This teacher seemed pretty reliable to me so far. Is that a regionalism? I just noticed that she starts the dialog with "Dove stanno le chiavi?" I don't know if that context alters the meaning.

Comment: I will have to agree with @DaG as there isn’t any general logical rule that differences “stare” from “essere”. Italian is full of exceptions :P